# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile' even if I change it to tf.io.gfile.GFile

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I have the following problem with my Python code :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in <cell line: 18>()
48     ## build vocab
49     if not os.path.isfile('vocab.txt'):
---> 50         _ = tl.nlp.create_vocab(processed_capts, word_counts_output_file=VOC_FIR, min_word_count=1)
51     else:
52         print("WARNING: vocab.txt already exists")

/content/tensorlayer/nlp.py in create_vocab(sentences, word_counts_output_file, min_word_count)
370
371     # Write out the word counts file.
--> 372     with tf.compat.v1.gfile.FastGFile(word_counts_output_file, "w") as f:
373         f.write("\n".join(["%s %d" % (w, c) for w, c in word_counts]))
374     print("Wrote vocabulary file: %s" % word_counts_output_file)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'

and the code part 1 is :

```
    ## build vocab
if not os.path.isfile('vocab.txt'):
    _ = tl.nlp.create_vocab(processed_capts, word_counts_output_file=VOC_FIR, min_word_count=1)
else:
    print("WARNING: vocab.txt already exists")
vocab = tl.nlp.Vocabulary(VOC_FIR, start_word="<S>", end_word="</S>", unk_word="<UNK>")
```

and the code part 2 in nlp.py file is :

```
    # Write out the word counts file.
with tf.compat.v1.gfile.FastGFile(word_counts_output_file, "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(["%s %d" % (w, c) for w, c in word_counts]))
print("Wrote vocabulary file: %s" % word_counts_output_file)
```

I change the gfile in nlp.py to tf.compat.v1.gfile.FastGFile but it didn't work
and it literally blows my mind anyone can help, please?

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Please post all code, error messages, and other output as plain text.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11286032)

Comment: sorry for that .... I'll edit it now

Comment: it should be fine now